# Finding average using three methods and a for loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

package averagewithmethods;

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class AverageWithMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput = "";
        double avgVal = 0;
        //calculateAvg(userInput);
        //getUserInput();
        printResults(userInput, avgVal);
    }

    public static String getUserInput() {
        String userInput;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter up to ten numbers in one line: ");
        userInput = scnr.nextLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    public static double calculateAvg(String userInput) {
        double avgVal = 0;
        double totSum = 0;
        int i;
        String newUserInput[] = getUserInput().split(" ");
        double[] userInputArray = new double[newUserInput.length];

        for (i = 0; i < newUserInput.length; ++i) {
            String userInputString = newUserInput[i];
            userInputArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(userInputString);
            totSum +=userInputArray[i];
            avgVal = totSum/newUserInput.length;
        }
        return avgVal;
    }

    public static void printResults(String userInput, double avgVal) {
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + getUserInput() + " is " + calculateAvg(userInput));
    }
}
```

This is my output.

```
Please enter up to ten numbers in one line: 10 20 30
Please enter up to ten numbers in one line: 10 20 30
The average of the numbers 10 20 30 is 20.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

The only thing I need to know is why does the prompt ("Please enter up to ten numbers in one line: ") print twice

Comment: Because you call it twice, both in your `printResults` method, and then again in the `calculateAve` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `getUserInput()` method twice: once in the `printResults()` method and once in the `calculateAvg()`.

You probably want to make the following change:

```
String newUserInput[] = getUserInput().split(" ");
```

to

```
String newUserInput[] = userInput.split(" ");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked in combination with the other suggestions made by @StriplingWarrior above!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void printResults(String userInput, double avgVal) {
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + getUserInput() + " is " + calculateAvg(userInput));
}
```

You're calling `getUserInput()` and `calculateAvg()` methods again here. Instead, just use the parameter variables you passed in.

```
public static void printResults(String userInput, double avgVal) {
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers " + userInput + " is " + avgVal);
}
```

Of course, to get the behavior you're looking for, you'll probably want to change things around a little in your other methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userInput = getUserInput();
    double avgVal = calculateAvg(userInput);

    printResults(userInput, avgVal);
}
```

And:

```
String newUserInput[] = userInput.split(" ");
```

Comment: @sharon: I'm glad I could help. Remember to mark the answer correct so other people know you're not still looking for help.